# No response on dataread with c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using windows forms app(.net framework) with c#. I'm trying when the customer try to decrease number on sql data, if its out off limits app will reminde to buy more of that item. item names list in combobox1 items. when ı write code below it give no error but app is not responding and didnt write data on sql.

ÜrünÇıkışı: decrease number of item on classes
ToplamÜrün: number of items(ı used sum because of so much in&out of the same product but on a different data)

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        con = new SqlConnection("server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog=SarfDepo;Integrated Security=true");
        cmd = new SqlCommand();
        con.Open();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "Select sum(ToplamÜrün) as toplam, avg(Limit) as limit from SarfDepoSayim where ÜrünAdi = '" + comboBox2.SelectedIndex + "' group by ÜrünAdi";
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            if (dr.GetInt32(0) <= dr.GetInt32(1))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ürün belirlenen limitin altına düştü. Lütfen Sipariş verin");
                ÜrünÇıkışı();
            }
            else
            {
                ÜrünÇıkışı();
            }
        }
        con.Close();
```

and my table desing :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SarfDepoSayim] (
[Id]          INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[ÜrünAdi]     VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[GirisTarihi] VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[CikisTarihi] VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[VerilenKisi] VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[GirenÜrün]   REAL         NULL,
[CikanÜrün]   REAL         NULL,
[ToplamÜrün]  REAL         NULL,
[Limit]       REAL         NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
```

);

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by, there is no response? No data or a timeout?

Comment: 1: There is no write, you are doing a read, only. Thus nothing will happen to the data in the database.

2: You would likely not want to structure your code this way. Having the SQL connection created, built, executed, and read inside the button2_Click method is likely going to make it very difficult for you to debug your code. 
3: Naming variables, methods, classes, etc. Is not really something you should skip out on, All classes, interfaces and abstracts, should be nouns, all method names should be verbs.

Comment: ÜrünÇıkışı is doing the writing job. its the class for a change the sql data.

Comment: @MustafaBektaş post enough code to reproduce the problem. If there's no data the loop won't run and nothing will be written even if that unfortunately named method does indeed execute an INSERT.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ım using stored procedure to writing data and it has insert

Comment: This code contains several bugs anyway. 1) Constructing a query from user input results in bad queries *and* SQL injection. You're comparing a number, `SelectedIndex`, with a field that may or may not be a string. Quoting means you're comparing that field with the string `'1'` instead of the number 1. It could be worse though. If you used a textbox a value like `'; DROP TABLE STUDENTS;--` would drop any table. 2) Connections, readers etc aren't closed safely which leads to leaks and long-running locks in the DB and

Comment: `ım using stored procedure to writing data and it has insert` which doesn't explain anything. Whatever that method does, it will never run if there are no data in the database alread

Comment: As for #3, displaying a message box inside the loop means the database connection *and all locks taken by the query* will remain open for far longer. In fact, if the unposted code tries to write to the same row using a different connection, it will be blocked by the already open connection

Comment: selectedindex for products names. Im displaying already added product names on combobox and adding sql server data for selected product name. ım trying to compare product numbers which is already writed they are real type not string. when ı try to write it on app to sql server it gave me so much error thats why ı used parse code.

Comment: if u have reccomend for me ı can change it. Beside we will use that app in our factory Im not gonna publish it soo security will not being a big problem for me because it will be on local and only 1 person will be use that app. I put messagebox in there because ım trying to concern user by saying you are taking this much product but we dont have enough backup this product thats why you must bought more. İf you have any idea in a different way to do that ım open for reccomend because I'm stuck and my brain already frozen :/